# How to update dacpac version during build process to be build number of the queued build?

Tags: tfs, dacpac

I am trying to update the version element in the DacMetadata.xml file of a .dacpac to match the build number of the build where the .sqlproj is being built.  I would prefer to do this in PowerShell, but can do it in C# if necessary.

I am using on-prem TFS 2018 and the vNext build.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an extension exists to version dacpac, you can check and test it:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-Versioning-Task

Comment: Have you checked the extension? Is it helpful?